# Create an array with all the links of the years' archive (of a custom post type)

Tags: php, array, custom-post-type-archives

I have a custom post type called "papers" and I need to create an array with all the archive links per year that exists. Something like:

```
array (
[0]=> 'http://www.example.com/2021/?post_type=papers'
[1]=> 'http://www.example.com/2019/?post_type=papers'// cause there's no post in 2020
[2]=> 'http://www.example.com/2017/?post_type=papers'
)
```

I know it's weird but I'm going to feed a chart js with it.

Comment: hope, this helps https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_archives/

Comment: @ManishPushkarJha thanks for your response, but I need the array  of the links to feed something else. `get_archives()` gives formated list with the links already on the text. I need the list of links like the example above.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just recieved this answer in the StackOF page and it worked, though I don't fully understand it.

```
 $links = wp_get_archives(array('echo'=>'0','format'=>'<link>'));
  $regex = '/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i';
  preg_match_all($regex, $links, $matches);
  $array_links = $matches[0];
  print_r($array_links);
```

Just added  `'post_type' => 'myCPT'` in the `wp_get_archives()` array and it worked.

Get to the real answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69365466/16825540

Comment: `'format'=>'<link>'` is wrong: the option is just `'link'` without the angle brackets. But I guess since you're just using a regex to extract the URLs that doesn't matter here - any text with the URLs in will do.

Comment: Ditto the echo parameter should be `0` (no quotes) or `false`. But I guess the quoted '0' works OK too if this works for you.

Comment: I guess... as I said, don't fully understand it, but it works... just like a lot of things in coding. Awesome, weird and strange world. Thanks for the comments, though!